# Postgres Group Linked List Query

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I want to group my object `Foo`, which has an attribute `left` and `right` which may be either null or contain the `pid` of another `Foo` object.

I want a way to group all objects that link together via a group by query. The id of each group can be random but must be distinct.

Example input

```
╔═════╦══════════╦════╦════╦
║ FO  ║ left     ║  right  ║
╠═════╬══════════╬═════════╬
║  1  ║     3    ║   2     ║
║  2  ║     1    ║         ║
║  3  ║          ║   1     ║
║  4  ║     5    ║   6     ║
║  5  ║          ║   4     ║
║  6  ║     4    ║         ║
╚═════╩══════════╩════╩════╩
```

Output:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦════╦════╦
║ FO  ║ group    ║         ║
╠═════╬══════════╬═════════╬
║  1  ║     1    ║         ║
║  2  ║     1    ║         ║
║  3  ║     1    ║         ║
║  4  ║     2    ║         ║
║  5  ║     2    ║         ║
║  6  ║     2    ║         ║
╚═════╩══════════╩════╩════╩
```

Comment: BTW: a (doubly) linked lis is not a very suitable data structure for a database. *why* is it a linked list? Is it only a *time series* within the "group" with some ordering among the entries?

Comment: @wildplasser care to elaborate ;) unfortunately its necessary for what im doing. What would be the more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Care to elaborate *why* it is necessary ? (per record you store **two** additional *pointers*, that don't contain information about the record, but about its position in the table  := information about other records)

Comment: I simplified my table to get to the root of the question. My table is geometric representation of an undirected graph

Comment: It may look like an undirected graph to you, to me it looks like a 1:1 mapping of some linear (list?) OO object to a database structure.

Comment: its not actually mapping to primary keys

Comment: If your `FO` column is not a primary key (and the {left,right} columns are not foreign keys) I'll eat my hat.

Comment: No idea why you are being a douche, but they are not fk, they represent geometric data. I oversimplified the query to understand the simplest case, I am not literally checking if left=right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive data structures need recursive queries. Example data:

```
create table foo(id int, lt int, rt int);
insert into foo values
(1, 3, 2),
(2, 1, null),
(3, null, 1),
(4, 5, 6),
(5, null, 4),
(6, 4, null);
```

Query:

```
with recursive find (id, lt, rt, ids) as (
    select id, lt, rt, array[id]
    from foo
union all
    select 
        r.id, f.lt, f.rt, 
        case when ids[1] < f.id then ids || f.id else f.id || ids end
    from find r
    join foo f on f.id = r.lt or f.id = r.rt
    where f.id <> all(ids)
    )
select distinct on (id) id, ids[1] as group
from find
order by id, array_length(ids, 1) desc;

 id | group 
----+-------
  1 |     1
  2 |     1
  3 |     1
  4 |     4
  5 |     4
  6 |     4
(6 rows)
```

Id of a group is not random, it's min(id) of its elements.

Comment: This is awesome! Will test now :D

Comment: What is the purpose of  `where f.id <> all(ids)` in the union all query ?

Comment: Without this checking the query will never end. This is the end of searching (in a branch) because we have found an element which was already processed.

Comment: Makes sense! Last question, how does this case work? `case when ids[1] < f.id then ids || f.id else f.id || ids end` ? This is such an amazing answer !

Comment: This ensures that the smallest element is always on first position in the array.

Comment: i.e. `if first element is less than new one then append this new one to the array, else prepend it`.

Comment: BTW: if the LL is correct (has no cycles) this is not needed. And, as I said in the comments the whole LL is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: @wildplasser - There is no word about cycles (or lack of them) in the question, so I couldn't make assumptions on this.

Comment: I know. No sweat, your answer is correct, but the OP basically has no idea what (s)he is talking about, IMHO. And the OO model  -> data model is so very wrong, as I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Modified from @klin

```
create table public.foo (
id numeric,
lt numeric,
rt numeric
);

insert into public.foo values
(1,3,2), (2,1,null), (3,null,1), 
(4,5,6), (5,null,4), (6,4,null);

with recursive find (id, lt, rt, grp) as (
    select 
        id, lt, rt, 
        id -- rightmost id for grouping
    from public.foo
    where rt is null -- Get the rightmost objects
    union all
    select 
        r.id, r.lt, r.rt, 
        grp -- kept constant from rightmost object on the list
    from public.foo r
    join find f on r.id = f.lt -- Traverse list from right to left
    -- Recursion will stop when all left ids are null
    )
select id, grp from find
order by grp, id;
```

- Take the rightmost objects.
- Traverse from right to left.
- Rightmost `id` is kept constant for grouping

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. You can add table name 'f.grp' in the recursive part but it's not necessary. Check this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8ea88/1)